# How should one concatenate a stream of arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, java-stream, fold

I would like to concatenate a stream of arrays via a mutable accumulator.

Currently I am doing the following for `Stream<Foo[]>`:

```
Foo[] concatenation = streamOfFooArrays.collect(Collector.of(
    ArrayList<Foo>::new,
    (acc , els ) -> {acc.addAll(Arrays.asList(els));},
    (acc1, acc2) -> {acc1.addAll(acc2); return acc1;},
    acc -> acc.toArray(new Foo[x.size()])
));
```

However, for something that feels quite generically useful, it's disappointing that the standard library doesn't provide something more immediate.

Have I overlooked something, or is there A Better Way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to flatten the elements of the arrays into a `Stream<Foo>` and then generate the output array using `toArray` :

```
Foo[] concatenation = streamOfFooArrays.flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                                       .toArray(Foo[]::new);
```

Comment: Well, that's a much better idea!  Thank you.